# How do I do a functional update?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a React app which connects to Firebase for authentication and storage.  Each user can have multiple sets of colours and multiple sets of symbols; these are used to create "Boxes".  Each Box has one colour set and one symbol set.

The "Create Box" form shows the user all their colour sets and symbol sets, listed in dropdowns.  The user can select the colour set and symbol set for their new Box from the dropdown.

First the blank form is shown, and then I'm using "useEffect" to connect to firebase to get a list of the user's colour sets and symbol sets.  Once each list is retrieved, the dropdowns are populated, and the default colour set and symbol set are selected.

The component looks like this:

```
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
      boxname: "",
      colourSet: "",  // Colour set to use for this Box - initially unset
      symbolSet: ""   // Symbol set to use for this Box - initially unset
    })

    const CreateBox = (props) => {
    
      const [colourSets,        setColourSets       ] = useState("") // List of colour sets
      const [symbolSets,        setSymbolSets       ] = useState("") // List of symbol sets
      const [formData,          updateFormData      ] = useState(initialFormData)
    
      const context = useContext(AuthUserContext)

      useEffect(() => {
    
        // Get all colour sets by signed-in user
        props.firebase.colourSetsByUser(context.uid).get().then(querySnapshot => {

        let coloursets = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

          let colourSet = { // Store colour set id and name
            id: doc.data().key,
            name: doc.data().name
          }
    
          coloursets.push(colourSet) // Add this colour set to coloursets array

          if(doc.data().isDefault) { // Automatically select the default colour set
            updateFormData({ ...formData, colourSet: colourSet.id})
          }
    
       })

       setColourSets(coloursets) // Add coloursets array to the state variable, colourSets

     })

     ... same thing for symbol sets ...
    
  }, [context.uid, props.firebase]);


  return (
    <div className="componentContent createChart">
      <h1>Create Chart</h1>
      <form className="innerForm createChartForm" noValidate autoComplete="off" >
        <TextField
          className="textField createChartTextField chartDescriptionTextField"
          variant="outlined"
          margin="normal"
          fullWidth
          name="boxname"
          value={formData.boxname}
          onChange={handleFormChange}
          label="Box Name"
          placeholder="Box Name"
          id="boxname" />
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={2} className="marginTopFormItem">
              <InputLabel
                id="selectColourSetLabel"
                className="selectLabel">Colour Set</InputLabel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={10} className="marginTopFormItem">
            {
              formData.colourSet && colourSets
              ?
                <Select
                  labelId="selectColourSetLabel"
                  id="selectColourSet"
                  fullWidth
                  className="selectBox selectWithLabel"
                  value={formData.colourSet || null}
                >
                {
                  colourSets.map(
                        (item) => <MenuItem key={uuidv4()} value={item.id}>{item.name}</MenuItem>)
                }
                </Select>
              : null
            }
            </Grid>
            
            ... same thing for symbol set selector ...

          </Grid>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            variant="contained"
            color="secondary"
            className="formButton marginTopFormItem"
          >Create</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}

export default withFirebase(CreateChart);
```

The issue I'm having is that this gives a warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'updateFormData(f => ...)' if you only need 'formData' in the 'updateFormData' call
```

If I include formData in the dependency array, the useEffect function is called repeatedly, effectively freezing the app.  If I remove the dependency array, the same thing happens.  I can only prevent the infinite cycle by leaving formData out of the dependency array,  so I assume I need to do a functional update, but I'm not sure what that is in this case.  I've found some examples online, but they were for more straightforward cases and I couldn't figure out how to extend them to what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating state from an effect which depends on that state will always cause an infinite loop.

Try using the lambda syntax for your update function so the effect doesn't have to close over `formData`.

```
updateFormData(prevFormData => ({ ...prevFormData, colourSet: colourSet.id }));
```

Edit:

Expanding of proper usage of hooks, it looks like you can simplify your effects a bit:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const defaultDoc = colourSets.find(doc => doc?.isDefault);
      updateFormData(p => ({ ...p, colourSet: defaultDoc.id }));
    }, [colourSets]);

    useEffect(() => {
      props.firebase.colourSetsByUser(context.uid).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        setColourSets(querySnapshot.val().map(({ key, name, isDefault }) => ({ id: key, name, isDefault })));
      });
    }, [context.uid, props.firebase]);
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's taken me a while to get back to this, but your solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

This is a lint warning from react. Usually it is good practice to include all dependecies that you use in the hook, well, because you depend on them in it. In special cases, the most common one being to run the useEffect only on mounting and leaving the array empty, it is ok to neglect the dependencies.
Just get rid of the warning with that comment above the array

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

It think it would be nice, especially if you are working with others to include a comment why you choose to neglect certain dependencies so they dont stumble over it again.

Comment: Maybe it's okay to leave out dependencies if your application is of trivial importance, but there's always a way to write it correctly. Usually I see missing dependencies when a single effect tries to encapsulate all the behaviour of a complex component. An effect should contain at most a single concern.